# Cannot access MapR with

Tags: mapr

```
sudo maprlogin generateticket -type service -user <user_name> -duration 14:0:0 -out /<directory_name>
```

returns the following error message.

```
"Operation failed. User has no established credentials on the cluster: <clustername>"
```

I tried various alternative users. I always ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
maplogin password
```

instead and it works.